# How to retain the values in input fields when form submit fails in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have this code in Laravel-5.8. There are two models:

```
class HrLeaveType extends Model
{ 
    protected $table = 'hr_leave_types';

    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    protected $fillable = [
                  'leave_type_name',
                  'leave_type_code',
                  'description',
              ];   

    public function leavetypedetail()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Hr\HrLeaveTypeDetail');
    }  
}

class HrLeaveTypeDetail extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'hr_leave_type_details';

    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    protected $fillable = [
                  'id',
                  'leave_type_id',
                  'company_id',
                  'employee_type_id',
                  'no_of_days',
              ];

    protected $casts = [
     'data' => 'array',
    ];

    public function leavetype()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Hr\HrLeaveType', 'leave_type_id', 'id');
    }   

    public function employeetype()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Hr\HrEmployeeType', 'employee_type_id', 'id' );
    }        
}
```

Request Rules

```
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'leave_type_name' => [
                 'required', 
                 'string',
                 'min:3',
                 'max:80',                 
                Rule::unique('hr_leave_types')->where(function ($query) {
               return $query->where('leave_type_name', $this->leave_type_name)
                  ->where('company_id', $this->company_id);
            })                
            ],     
            'leave_type_code' => [
                 'nullable', 
                 'string',
                 'max:10',                 
                Rule::unique('hr_leave_types')->where(function ($query) {
               return $query->where('leave_type_code', $this->leave_type_code)
                  ->where('company_id', $this->company_id);
            })                
            ],    
            'no_of_days'           => 'required|array',
            'no_of_days.*' => [
                 'required', 
                 'numeric',
                 'max:120'               
            ],                                         
            'employee_type_id'           => 'required|array', 
            'employee_type_id.*' => [
                 'required',                 
            ],                     

        ];
    }      
}
```

Controller

```
public function create()
{
    $userCompany = Auth::user()->company_id;

    $employeetypes   =       HrEmployeeType::where('company_id', $userCompany)->get(); 
    $leavetype = new HrLeaveType();
    
    return view('leave.leave_types.create')
            ->with('leavetype', $leavetype)
            ->with('employeetypes', $employeetypes);
}

public function store(StoreLeaveTypeRequest $request)
{
    $userCompany = Auth::user()->company_id;
        $leavetype = new HrLeaveType();
        $leavetype->leave_type_name             = $request->leave_type_name;
        $leavetype->leave_type_code             = $request->leave_type_code;
        $leavetype->description                 = $request->description;

    $leavetype->save();        

        foreach ($request->employee_type_id as $key => $employee_type_id){

    $insert_array = [
            'no_of_days'                        => $request->no_of_days[$key],
            'employee_type_id'                  => $request->employee_type_id[$key],                
            'leave_type_id'                     => $leavetype->id,
        ];

        HrLeaveTypeDetail::create($insert_array );

         }
         
            Session::flash('success', 'Leave Type is created successfully');
            return redirect()->route('leave.leave_types.index');        
    }
}
```

LeaveTypeDetail is dynamically created

create.blade

```
@if (Session::has('error'))
    <div class="alert alert-warning" align="left">
        <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
        <strong>!</strong> {{Session::get('error')}}
    </div>
@endif  

<br>
@include('partials._messages')   

   <form  action="{{route('leave.leave_types.store')}}" method="post" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       {{csrf_field()}}
       
       
       <div class="card-body">
        <div class="form-body">
        <div class="row">  

          <div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label"> Leave Type Name:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
              <input  type="text" name="leave_type_name" value="{{ old('leave_type_name', $leavetype->leave_type_name) }}" placeholder="Enter leave type name" class="form-control @error('leave_type_name') is-invalid @enderror">
                @error('leave_type_name')
                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                    </span>
                @enderror                 
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label"> Leave Type Code:</label>
              <input  type="text" name="leave_type_code" value="{{ old('leave_type_code', $leavetype->leave_type_code) }}" placeholder="Enter leave typecode" class="form-control @error('leave_type_code') is-invalid @enderror">
                @error('leave_type_code')
                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                    </span>
                @enderror                 
            </div>
          </div>                
            
            
          <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Description</label>
                <textarea rows="2" name="description" class="form-control @error('description') is-invalid @enderror" value="{{old('description',$leavetype->description)}}" placeholder="Enter Description here ...">{{old('description',$leavetype->description)}}</textarea>
                @error('description')
                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                    </span>
                @enderror                 
            </div>
          </div>

   <div class="col-sm-12">
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col">Employee Type<span style="color:red;">*</span></th>
                            <th scope="col">Leave Days<span style="color:red;">*</span></th>
                            <th scope="col"><a class="btn btn-info addRow"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a></th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td width="60%">                    
                                    <option value="0" selected="true" disabled="true">Select Employee Type</option>
                                     @if($employeetypes->count() > 0 )
                                        @foreach($employeetypes as $employeetype)
                                         <option name="employee_type_id[]"  value="{{$employeetype->id}}">{{$employeetype->employee_type_name}}</option>
                                        @endforeach
                                    @endif                                         
                                </select>
                            </td>
                            <td width="35%"><input type="text" name="no_of_days[]" placeholder="Enter leave days here" class="form-control no_of_days" max="120"></td>
                            <td width="5%"><a class="btn btn-danger remove"> <i class="fa fa-times"></i></a></td>
                         </tr>
                        </tbody>

                    </table>
        </div>

       </div>
     </div>
    </div>          
    <!-- /.card-body -->
    <div class="card-footer">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">{{ trans('global.save') }}</button>
      <button type="button" onclick="window.location.href='{{route('leave.leave_types.index')}}'" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
    </div>           
       
    </form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.addRow').on('click', function () {
            addRow();

        });
        function addRow() {
            var addRow = '<tr>\n' +
               '     <td width="60%"><select class="form-control select2bs4" data-placeholder="Choose Employee Type" tabindex="1" name="employee_type_id[]">\n' +
                       '             <option value="0" selected="true" disabled="true">Select Employee Type</option>\n' +
                       '              @if($employeetypes->count() > 0 )\n' +
                       '                 @foreach($employeetypes as $employeetype)\n' +
                       '                 <option value="{{$employeetype->id}}">{{$employeetype->employee_type_name}}</option>\n' +
                       '                 @endforeach\n' +
                       '             @endif\n' +
                       '         </select></td>\n' +
                   '     <td width="35%"><input type="text" name="no_of_days[]" placeholder="Enter leave days here" class="form-control no_of_days" max="120"></td>\n' +
               '     <td width="5%"><a   class="btn btn-danger remove"> <i class="fa fa-times"></i></a></td>\n' +
               '    </tr>';
            $('tbody').append(addRow);
            addRemoveListener();
        };
    addRemoveListener();
});
</script>
```

One leave type has many leave type details. For the controller and view, I have dynamic form input.
leave_type_details are arrays.

When user submits, if action fails all the fields should retail their values. This happens to only leave_type, but leave_type_details fields did not retain their values. It clears off.

How do I achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

in blade :

```
@if(old('input_name'))
@foreach(old('input_name') as $key => $value)
<your_html>{{old("input_name.{$key}"}}</your_html>
@endforeach
@endif
```